# Floating Point Accuracy Problems While Calculating Pi

Tags: python

I'm trying to use random numbers to estimate the value of Pi.
The [example I started with](https://theabbie.github.io/blog/estimate-pi-using-random-numbers.html) obviously has some problems which is a good thing as it means I have to understand it so I can fix it.

```
# Expected Result 3.141592653589793238
#
from math import sqrt
from random import random
# number of fandom points
N=100000
# number of points inside
I=0
for i in range(N):
  #print("I="+str(I))
  #Generate random point in 1x1 square
  x=random()
  y=random()
  # Is the point inside the circle?
  # r=sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
  #print(str(r))
  #if r<1:
  If (x*x + y*y) <1:    # Update 2
    I+=1
# print("Pi=" + str(4*I/N))
print("Pi=" + str(4*I)/N)) # Update 3
```

Expected Result

```
3.141592653589793238
```

Actual Results

- 100,000 Iterations

  ```
    Pi=3.14736
    Pi=3.14448
    Pi=3.14424
  ```
- 1,000,000 Iterations

  ```
    Pi=3.141496
    Pi=3.141356
    Pi=3.138
  ```

I would have expected the results to be more consistent.
How can I add more precision to the calculations?

**UPDATE** 
I modified the code to remove sqrt and ** as recommended in the comments.  I cranked up the iterations to 4,000,000 but it didn’t make a lot of difference.  It is still only accurate to about 2 decimal places.  How can I add more precision to the calculation.  (That question was in the title but it was edited out)

2,000,000 iterations

```
Pi=3.141342
Pi=3.141328
Pi=3.143074
Pi=3.139084
```

4,000,000 iterations

```
Pi=3.142605
Pi=3.141509
Pi=3.140663
Pi=3.143194
```

**UPDATE 2** 
I changed the final calculation to the following.

```
import decimal

result=decimal.Decimal(4*I/N)
print("Pi=" + str(result))
```

4,000,000 iterations with decimal.Decimal()

```
Pi=3.14080899999999996197175278211943805217742919921875
Pi=3.143496999999999985675458447076380252838134765625
Pi=3.14080899999999996197175278211943805217742919921875
Pi=3.141859999999999875086587053374387323856353759765625
```

40,000,000 iterations with

```
decimal.Decimal()
Pi=3.141386900000000093058361017028801143169403076171875
Pi=3.1414208999999999605279299430549144744873046875
Pi=3.1414591999999998961357050575315952301025390625
Pi=3.14168000000000002813749233609996736049652099609375
```

This latest test looks like I have achieved accuracy of 3 decimal places but the results still look odd with big rows of 99999 or 00000.  Any other ideas what is going on here?

Last a couple of larger itterations but I think the increase in accuracy is diminishing

100,000,000 Iterations  (yes 100 million)

```
Pi=3.141542439999999825062104719108901917934417724609375
Pi=3.141720879999999826992507223621942102909088134765625
Pi=3.141750519999999990972128216526471078395843505859375
Pi=3.14174343999999994281324688927270472049713134765625
Pi=3.14132400000000000517275111633352935314178466796875
```

1,000,000,000 Iterations  (1 billion too a while on my old laptop :))

```
Pi=3.141603959999999862162667341181077063083648681640625
```

**Update 3** 
I moved the brackets in final calculation as described by @Michael Butscher however even with 1 billion iterations the I only consistently obtained 3 decimal places accurately.  Maybe I have hit some other limitation perhaps the sudo randomness of Python random numbers?  I'll call this exercise done and incorporate my findings into my actual project.
OK I couldn't resist I did 10 billion as well
Surprisingly it didn't make much difference

1,000,000 Iterations

```
Pi=3.142056
Pi=3.136428
Pi=3.1407
Pi=3.141612
```

10,000,000 Iterations

```
Pi=3.142806
Pi=3.142266
Pi=3.141996
Pi=3.1422232
```

100,000,000 Iterations

```
Pi=3.14151576
Pi=3.1417604
Pi=3.1415038
Pi=3.1413738
```

1,000,000,000

```
Pi=3.141553108
Pi=3.1415895
Pi=3.141629112
```

10,000,000,000  Iterations  (10 Billion)
Took about 12 hours to execute

```
Pi=3.1416011832
```

Comment: At least you can make it faster by omitting the `sqrt`. If the square root of a number is between 0 and 1, the number itself is as well.

Comment: Do not use `sqrt`, nor `**`. It is just a waste of time and precision. Directly compare `x*x + y*y` to `r*r`. Results should not be really better but at least it is easier for the machine...

Comment: You can also use `numpy` to generate a full array of random points, rather than doing it in a loop. But Monte-Carlo estimation will be pretty slow to converge, so to compute PI to a higher accuracy, you will need to simulate more points anyway

Comment: Regarding update 2 you changed the **presentation** of the results. To change the calculation, use `result=decimal.Decimal(4*I)/N`

Comment: @Michael I’m not sure how the change in location of the brackets will effect the result. I’m currently running a really large number of iterations at  1 billion.

Comment: Your variant just calculates a usual float division, converts it to a Decimal and shows that with all digits of the float where most of the righter ones (after the 000... or 999... block) are useless. My variant converts the int exactly to a Decimal and then divides by the other int so that the result is exact for the defined precision of the Decimal (by default 28 digits).

Comment: Ahhh I see I’ll give that a go tonight.  You should add that as a solution so I can give you the credit.  Otherwise I need to answer my own question (again) 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final division is currently done as

```
result=decimal.Decimal(4*I/N)
```

but this means that the division is using float arithmetic which produces imprecise results like `3.141603959999999862162667341181077063083648681640625` instead of `3.14160396`.

Moreover the division can produce nonsense due to an overflow for very large integers to divide.

Instead of that, the int can be converted exactly to a Decimal first and then be divided by another int:

```
result=decimal.Decimal(4*I)/N
```

This time the division uses the implementation for Decimal which is exact for the defined precision (28 digits by default).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution all in one place.
I was hoping for a better result.  Perhaps this needs more iterations.

```
from math import sqrt
from random import random
from decimal import Decimal

# number of random points
N=10000000
# number of points inside
I=0
for i in range(N):
  #Generate random point in 1x1 square
  x=Decimal(str(random()))
  y=Decimal(str(random()))
  # Is the point inside the circle?
  if (x*x + y*y) < Decimal("1"):    
    I+=1
result=Decimal(4*I)/N
print( "Expected Result= 3.141592653589793238 ")
print("          Result="+str(result))

# Exp    3.141592653589793238
# Result=3.141676  Iterations=10,000,000
# Result=3.1418548 Iterations=10,000,000
```